# Golang download and '$GOPATH not set'

Tags: macos, go, terminal, gopath

I downloaded *Golang* *1.11.1*, but in the terminal when I type `go version`, I get: `go version go1.6.2 darwin/amd64`.

When I type `which go` in the terminal, I get: `/usr/local/bin/go`

I can see in `/usr/local` that there is a **go** directory, and when I open the file `VERSION`, it says *1.11.1*

When I try `go get https://github.com/blablabla` in the terminal, it spits out `package github.com/google/uuid: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath`.

What is the issue here? Could it be that I am one of the users (and not the original user) on my mac? To get to my files, I have to go to `Users/myusername` first... How do I change my `GOPATH` so that this works?

Thank you -S

Update: I set my `$GOPATH` to `/Users/myusername/go` by editing my `bash_profile`, but the version still has not changed, although I re-downloaded *Go*.

Comment: run `go env` and check the value of your `GOROOT` and or `GOBIN` variables. It's possible that you have an older golang version (go1.6.2) installed (possibly with homebrew)

Comment: GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.2/libexec". How can I change this? Thank you!

Comment: Try setting the value in the `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (depending on which shell you're using)

Comment: Resolved! I ran 'brew upgrade' and go is now updated. Not sure if that is a long term solution though...

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

1. You can go to **user/local/go/src**

   if the golang is install .it show many file.
2. Then you can open terminal. and type **go env**
3. after that set the **$GOPATH**

   **export GOPATH=/user/local/go**
4. Also set the **$GOBIN**

   **export GOBIN= $GOPATH/bin**